# Disable Highlight Matched Parentheses in ViM : "let loaded_matchparen = 1" not working

Tags: vim, brackets

How to disable auto highlighting of Matched Parentheses (cursor briefly jumping to the matched bracket, when a new bracket is inserted) in ViM?

When I faced this issue in my earlier company, then I was able to resolve it by adding below line to my `.vimrc`

```
let loaded_matchparen = 1
```

Now in my new company I am facing the same problem. But now the issue doesn't go even with above line in my `.vimrc`.

I tried adding, `NoMatchParen` to my .vimrc, I am getting following error when opening ViM:

```
Error detected while processing <...>/.vimrc:
E492: Not an editor command: NoMatchParen
```

Pl. let me know a work around for this annoying issue.

FYR, Output of my `$ vim --version`:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Feb 11 2012 21:05:37)
Compiled by rvictor@depbldrh61
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
+conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff 
+digraphs +dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi 
+file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext 
-hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall 
+linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname 
+mouse +mouseshape +mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm 
-mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg 
-osfiletype +path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile 
-python -python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs 
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 +toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup +X11 -xfontset +xim 
+xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/depot/vim-7.3/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12     -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0   -lXt -lm -lncurses -lselinux -lacl
```

Comment: Please add the full output of `$ vim --version` to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your vimrc for `showmatch` or `sm`.

`:set noshowmatch` or `:set nosm` disables the brief jumping.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work for me. Tried with both vim and nvim, on Linux.

Comment: did not work with ubuntu gvim with vim 8.0, but restarting  did work for me

Answer (score 32):

As none of the above answers worked for me (OSX Sierra), I will provide what I think should work in any (of the usual?) configuration of vim.

As the OP, in OSX vim relies on the plugin `MatchParen` for highlighting the matching parentheses. Thus, `:set noshowmatch` will not work. However, `:NoMatchParen` works.

The question is now to configure our `~/.vimrc` so that this plugin is disabled by default when opening a file.

As it's common to import our `~/.vimrc` from old system to any new accounts, and in the new system highlighting might be toggled by `show match`, the following will address the issue automatically in both instances:

In your `~/.vimrc` add the following lines:

```
" Disable parentheses matching depends on system. This way we should address all cases (?)
set noshowmatch
" NoMatchParen " This doesnt work as it belongs to a plugin, which is only loaded _after_ all files are.
" Trying disable MatchParen after loading all plugins
"
function! g:FckThatMatchParen ()
    if exists(":NoMatchParen")
        :NoMatchParen
    endif
endfunction

augroup plugin_initialize
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * call FckThatMatchParen()
augroup END
```

**Note**: the `END` in the last `augroup` line is important. Without it you get a pesky notification when calling `vim` **before your file gets open**:

```
$ vi my file.txt  
plugin_initialize  
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: :set noshowmatch also didn't work on my machine (Arch) - this answer worked for me though.

Comment: this worked for me. please select this as the answer. thanks!!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, nothing else in this thread worked.

Comment: What's up with that function name prefix?  Is that some kind of a technical acronym?

Answer (score 32):

```
let g:loaded_matchparen=1
```

worked for me!

It sets a flag that tells code under `/vim/vim81/plugin/matchparen.vim` to not assert itself.

Comment: Don't know why this works in vimrc, but it does. Thanks.

Comment: Running vim on Ubuntu, I can temporarily disable matching parens by typing: `:NoMatchParen`, but then I can't seem to access that key from .vimrc.

The above answer was the only one that worked for me.

Comment: Works in nvim as well.

Comment: worked on my vimrc using nvim!

Answer (score 3):

If you have disabled the MatchParen plugin, then there will be no command `NoMatchParen` available (since loading the plugin is skipped).
What exactly do you want to achieve? Perhaps you are looking for the `:set noshowmatch` command (which you can put into your .vimrc)?

Comment: For future readers: using the command `NoMatchParen` for checking is still useful now. And If you're Neovim macOS user, you still need to set `vim.g.loaded_matchparen = 1` to disable the plugin.